# Connect to tfs Azure from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I created my first `Team Project` in my account on the [tfs 2012 in the cloud](https://tfs.visualstudio.com/).

Now, how can I connect to it through `Visual Studio 2012` from my pc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the answer to your question at the link bellow

[Connect Visual Studio to your team project](https://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/code/connect-vs/#connectvs)

Furtheremore, there is another solution to do this.

1. Open Visual studio 2012
2. From the menu bar, choose **View** -> **Team Explorer**
3. In Team Explorer view, choose the **Context Menu Icon** next to the team project name, and  then choose **Projects and My Teams** -> **Connect to Team Projects**.
4. In the Connect to Team Project dialog box, choose the Servers button.
5. In the Add/Remove Team Foundation Server dialog box, choose the Add button.
6. In the Add Team Foundation Server dialog box, type the name or URL for the server.
   In your case (https://yourname.visualstudio.com).

During the process you may be asked to enter the credentials from your windows live account (outlook.com, hotmail.com etc)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.